# Query In Realm Database : Find All Objects Containing Query String

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I've a set of different type of Objects persisted in Realm Database. Now I want to Query certain type of Objects including all of the fields of that Object. The method I wrote below, is getting all of the declared fields of the Object and iterates on the fields to check if the given query string is contained.

It works fine for the String fields types but throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field 'documentCompletionStatus': type mismatch. Was STRING, expected INTEGER.` for integer values since my search query object is string. I skip the Non-String values for now as a workaround but I'm curious if it's possible to search it in all of the fields.

For example, if the user wants to search an integer value targeting the "Age" field of the Objects, I cannot make it work this way.

```
public <T extends RealmObject> List<T> searchDatabase(Class<T> clazz, String searchQuery) {

    /* Begin Query */
    RealmQuery<T> query = realmDatabase.where(clazz).beginGroup();

    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

        /* Skip NON-String Values */
        if (!fields[i].getType().equals(String.class)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (i == 0) {
            query.contains(fields[i].getName(), searchQuery, false);
        } else {
            query.or().contains(fields[i].getName(), searchQuery, false);
        }
    }

    /* Return All Objects Found */
    return query.endGroup().findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. The reason your code doesn't work is because `contains()` only work for String fields (http://realm.io/docs/java/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#contains-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), so when you try to use `contains()` it with a integer field it will fail.

If you want to search for different datatypes you will need to cast them to such, something like:

```
public <T extends RealmObject> List<T> searchDatabase(Class<T> clazz, String searchQuery) {

    RealmQuery<T> query = realmDatabase.where(clazz).beginGroup();

    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        Class<?> type = fields[i].getType();
        String fieldName = fields[i].getName();

        if (i > 0) {
            query.or()
        }   

        if (type.equals(String.class)) {
            query.contains(fieldName, searchQuery)
        } else if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
            query.equalTo(fieldName, Integer.parseInt(searchQuery))
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    /* Return All Objects Found */
    return query.endGroup().findAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, that's what I'm doing now. But I thought there might be a way to do it in Realm itself. Are you guys planning to have a sort of query method that we can query in all of the fields ? something like `query.containsAll(searchQuery)`, regardless of field name.

Comment: We don't have any plans at the moment, but feel free to create an feature request on GitHub. There it is easier to discuss the exact use case and it is easier to see if others are interested in that functionality as well.

Comment: was searching for something like group

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can use this code. You can cover all the primitives i think. I have added code for String, int and float.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ReflectionTest {
    String stringValue;
    int intValue;
    float floatValue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] fields = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {

            if (field.getType().toString().contains("int")) {
                System.out.println("int Name \t" + field.getName());
            }

            if (field.getType().toString().contains("float")) {
                System.out.println("float Name \t" + field.getName());
            }

            if (field.getType().toString().contains("String")) {
                System.out.println("String Name \t" + field.getName());
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What this code does is, printing out the Field Names. Finding the type of the field is already implemented in my code. I skip Non-String values in a similar manner. Read the question again, and let me know if you didn't understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry my bad, got the question.

If you have a non string type say Integer, You can convert integer  to string (String.valueOf([int/float/double/long/char/bolean])) and then use contains method ??

Comment: yes, possible. But the problem is that I don't know if the searchQuery is totally integer or String or mixed of different types, all the time. This method needs to be as generic as possible and has to work with all kind of data types.

Comment: I believe this is more about Realm I should not be creating work arounds like that.